# SpellingCorrectionList for custom language (Italian)

Tags: natural-language, dictionary, spellchecker

```
SpellingCorrectionList["ciao",Language -> Italian]
```

Says there are no Spelling dictionaries for Italian.
On the other hand, `RandomWord[1, Language->Italian]` shows that a plain italian dictionary is present somehow.

So, how could we implement a spelling correction function for languages that are not supported by `SpellingCorrectionList`?